# Angular p-inputswitch on page load

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an input switch on my site:

```
<label>Bonus</label>
<p-inputSwitch formControlName="bonus"
  (onChange)="clickBonusChecked($event)"
  onLabel="yes"
  offLabel="no">
```

```
<p class="text-small" *ngIf="checked">Information about the bonus</p>
```

I want the text-small to show when the input switch is checked. This works, but not on page load and the input is already checked. It just shows "yes" and not the text.. When I put it on "no" and then "yes", the text shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Reactive Form, you don't need to use `clickBonusChecked($event)`. You can directly put **value** of `bonus` in `*ngIf`. So whenever the form is loaded with yes value it will show the bonus element.
Code will look like this:

```
     <form [formGroup]="form" >
       <p-inputSwitch  formControlName="bonus"  onLabel="yes"
  offLabel="no"></p-inputSwitch>
    <p class="text-small" *ngIf="form.value.bonus">Information about the bonus</p>
     </form>
```